# How to change Excel data points in graph with multiple variables?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this Excel sheet and I want to know how the values of the variables in the columns interact with the graph data points. Changing the value of the variable causes the graph to shift, however I'm unable to understand how? What is the formula of the line? Does anybody know how this is done in Excel? A link to the Excel sheet, since apparently you cannot upload on here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mAJGm9ATgwF2KzRR18pAS4fWN0bsbUVm/view

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking.  It might be easier to follow if you describe a scenario of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why does the graph change when I change the value of for example pKa = 1 to pKa = 5? Which Excel tools/plugins are used to accomplish this?

Comment: The graph is a visual representation of the data.  If you change the data being graphed, the visual representation of it changes.  If you're asking how a graph is produced via code, that's not really on-topic here.

Comment: (1) People are reluctant to download complex files (like spreadsheets) from the Internet, especially from unfamiliar users.  If fixer1234’s comments haven’t resolved your question, you may post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) or the [Plain Text Tables generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) site if you want.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) “What is the formula of the line?”  As fixer1234 says, the chart is a (dynamic) representation of the data.  If you’re asking “What is the formula of the data?”, don’t ask us — it’s your spreadsheet; just look at it.  (3) If you don’t know how to tell which cells in a spreadsheet are manually-entered constants and which are values computed by formulas, you need to do some research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while OP accepted the answer, their comment indicates this was a courtesy and not due to the answer being the correct solution, and the question remains difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is plotted from the data tab of your spreadsheet. It uses columns A and B to create the extraction curve graph that is shown in the acid tab.

In order to find out from which data points a graph is being created you should select the graph (chart in excel terms), right click on it and click on Select data from the pop up menu.  It will show you the data that is being used for the plot.

I also found the equation that is used `=1-(1-(acid!$B$4*acid!$B$5)/(acid!$B$4*acid!$B$5 + 1 + 10^(A6-acid!$B$6)))^acid!$B$7`. So when you change B6 in acid tab (i.e your pKa), the curve changes.

Comment: I figured it out shortly after posting, nevertheless thank you!